# Finding min/max timestamp for consecutive times MySQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp, time-series, duration, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that records timestamps for different users. I need to find the duration of consecutive timestamps for each user based on which ANT picked up the signal.

```
CREATE TABLE F30T (
    RN AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY,
    UID VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    ANT INT NOT NULL,
    ScanTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO F30T (
    UID,
    ANT,
    ScanTime)
  VALUES 
    ('4000bcc3584f', 1, '2018-08-17 19:19:04'),
    ('4000bcc3584f', 1, '2018-08-17 19:19:05'),
    ('4000bcc3584f', 1, '2018-08-17 19:19:06'),
    ('4000bcc3584f', 1, '2018-08-17 19:19:25'),
    ('4000bcc3584f', 4, '2018-08-17 19:19:26'),
    ('4000bcc3584f', 2, '2018-08-17 19:19:27'),
    ('4000bcc3584f', 2, '2018-08-17 19:19:28'),
    ('4000bcc3584f', 2, '2018-08-17 19:19:29'),
    ('4000bcc2a44f', 4, '2018-08-17 19:19:05'),
    ('4000bcc2a44f', 4, '2018-08-17 19:19:06'),
    ('4000bcc2a44f', 1, '2018-08-17 19:19:06'),
    ('4000bcc2a44f', 4, '2018-08-17 19:19:07');
```

So with this example above I would want it to show me a table like this:

```
    UID         ANT        MIN(ScanTime)          MAX(ScanTime)       Duration
4000bcc3584f     1      2018-08-17 19:19:04    2018-08-17 19:19:06       3
4000bcc3584f     2      2018-08-17 19:19:27    2018-08-17 19:19:29       3
4000bcc2a44f     4      2018-08-17 19:19:05    2018-08-17 19:19:06       3
```

Where it picks out the consecutive timestamps for the user and ANT and groups them in min/max and finds the duration. I am using MySQL by the way, but this will eventually be translated into a python program

Thanks in advance for your help-I'm new to the world of coding and just trying to find my way through.

Comment: Which MySQL version? .. use `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.13

Comment: Besides should the datetimes `2018-08-17 23:59:59`, `2018-08-18 00:00:00` also treated as consecutive?

Comment: yes, for sure :)

Comment: I assume the last record should be `4000bcc2a44f     4      2018-08-17 19:19:05    2018-08-17 19:19:06       2` instead?

Comment: yes, that was my mistake-let me fix it

Comment: i figured that i have posted a answer for you... Besides i assume the last record should be `4000bcc2a44f 4 2018-08-17 19:19:05 2018-08-17 19:19:07 3` because ANT 4 has 3 consecutive timestamps `19:19:05`, `19:19:06` and `19:19:07`